# PL SQL Handling trigger errors

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

I have script files with thousands of sql `INSERT INTO` lines. Some of these lines will insert data that's already in the database, so I want to catch these errors and just bypass it. Is there a way to catch errors thrown by a trigger and ignoring it?

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20053: Username must be unique
ORA-06512: at "MY_TRIGGER", line 18
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'MY_TRIGGER'
ORA-06512: at line 3
```

I could do this with unique constraints by catching a `DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX` and then doing `NULL`, but this does not work for the above trigger error.

Comment: Another option to consider : insert into a temp table and then into the main table. Duplicate usernames might have other columns that you want to keep or keep the first created username. A lot of such tasks will be easier if you have some kind of data cleansing by going the temp table route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own exception and use that just like you would use one of the default exception handlers like `dup_val_on_index`.

```
DECLARE
  l_unique_username_ex exception;
  pragma exception_init( l_unique_username_ex, -20053 );
BEGIN
  <<your INSERT statement>>
EXCEPTION
  WHEN l_unique_username_ex
  THEN
    NULL; -- Ignore the error
END;
```

In general, though, it would make more sense to modify your scripts so that they only try to insert rows that do not already exist rather than letting the trigger try to flag them and then ignoring the error.